# How to identify and address the root cause of a connection timeout?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, centos6, linux-networking

**Background:** I'm trying to connect to an SFTP server to transfer some files. However, I noticed that I can't connect from it from one particular server. I'm able to connect from other machines on the same network so I could say, it may be something wrong local with that server.

```
SERVER-OK#1   ---> sftpserver.com:22
SERVER-FAIL#2 ---> sftpserver.com:22
```

**What I've tried / found out so far:**

1. **`traceroute`** - there are different trace results. The failing server, doesn't finish the trace.

   > ```
   > traceroute to sftpserver.com (10.10.10.10), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets 
   > 1  10.10.10.1 (10.10.10.254)  0.681 ms  1.209 ms  1.435 ms 
   > 2  99.99.99.99 (99.99.99.254)  1.890 ms  1.820 ms  1.741 ms
   > 3  * * *
   > 4  * * *
   > 30 * * *
   > ```
2. **`ping`** - times out for sftpserver.com only from SERVER-FAIL#2. I can ping google etc. but not sftserver.com. If done from other servers, ping is okay.
3. **`iptables`** - disabled.
4. **`proxies`** - `http_proxy` is set in `bash_profile`.
5. **`firewall`** - allows port 22 SSH.
6. **`reboot server`** - I know, right? I'm kinda desperate.

Is there anything else I should be inspecting?

Comment: Packet captures.  Always go for the packet captures.

Comment: Comparing routing between machines where it works and those where it doesn't might also be useful.

Comment: Do you have switches/routers or other devices in between the server and the machine that has this problem?

Comment: Why are the DNS names showing as IP addresses in your traceroute?  10.10.10.1 is the DNS name for 10.10.10.254?  very strange.  Can you use mtr instead?  I want to see what it shows,

Comment: Either way, it would appear you have routers in between.  Most likely you're missing a route.  Are you running a routing protocol or is it all static?  Are these routers actually routing or doing NAT?  Are those real IP's or have you doctored them.  99.99.99.99 is rather unusual

Comment: @JennyD I did the route compare and they're the same.

Comment: @womble, Will try that next.

Comment: @Matt, I'm not sure as they are virtually hosted. And regarding the IPs, I changed them... let me run mtr instead. :)

Comment: One difference between the working servers and this failing one is that the latter has a modified `sshd_config` to use `internal-sftp`. I haven't tried changing this to its original configuration... this could possibly be the culprit.

Comment: There is literally no way that an sshd config can affect traceroute.

Comment: Run tcpdump on the server and use that to see if it sees packets from your trouble client

Answer (score 2):

If you know it works from other servers, then you just have to determine what is different about the relationship between the two servers that don't work. Since your trace is timing out and ping fails, there's a basic connectivity problem between those hosts. Compare settings between the faulty server and the known good hosts. In particular:

- Is the gateway set and does it match other hosts on the subnet?
- Are the network address and the subnet mask correct?
- Can the problem host reach any/all other hosts on the network ok?
- Does that bad traceroute traverse the same path as the successful ones from other hosts?

A subnet mask that is slightly off, for example, will allow you to reach nearly all other hosts fine, but makes a particular subset "invisible" because your host doesn't think it's on the same local network. The `route -n` command should show you the basic gateway, network, and subnet info.

Comment: The `route` seems to be the same, and our network guy confirmed. He's also puzzled. Anyway, one difference between the working servers and this failing one is that the latter has a modified `sshd_config` to use `internal-sftp`. I haven't tried changing this to its original configuration... this could possibly be the culprit.